# Make mySQL column unique for each foreign key

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following column in my database:

```
Item:
id int PRIMARY KEY,
name string,
foreign_id FOREIGN KEY
```

Is there a way without querying the database before insertion each time, that one foreign key cannot contain two rows with the same name?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you want to add an (unique) index for your foreign key column.
The SQL command to add that is

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `mytable_idx__1` (`foreign_id`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you might want to use the UNIQUE constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE (
    id          INT PRIMARY KEY
  , name        VARCHAR(50) --or whatever you need
  , foreign_id  INT UNIQUE
    FOREIGN KEY (foreign_id) REFERENCES...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As i Understand using FOREIGN KEY (foreign_id) REFERENCES --- will solve it. And make sure that the always make a `unique key` of table as `foreign key` for other table.

```
CREATE TABLE profile
( 
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(50),
  FOREIGN KEY (name)
     REFERENCES member (name) 
     ON DELETE CASCADE
     ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```